# Change of hook state in other component is not permanent when component is unmounted

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, render

I have a component (App) where I store hook state if user is logged in, I want user to be logged when /dashboard is rendered and I want to keep that info even when /dashboard is unmounted. I use it in DefaultNavbar to determine right buttons. In my code state of isLogged is set to true when I am in /dashboard, but when I render /account the state of isLogged is again false. How to keep the value of isLogged when Dashboard is unmounted? Here is the code of App.

```
function App() {
  const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DefaultNavbar isLogged={isLogged}/>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/createUser" >
            <CreateUser />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard setIsLogged={setIsLogged} />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/redirectAfterLogin" >
            <RedirectAfterLogin />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/account" >
            <Account />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code of Dashboard:

```
export default function Dashboard(props) {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.setIsLogged(true);
        return () => {
            props.setIsLogged(true);
        }
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

And code of DefaultNavbar:

```
export default function DefaultNavbar(props) {
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar bg="warning" >
                <Navbar.Brand>
                    <Image src={logo} />
                </Navbar.Brand>

                <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    {!props.isLogged &&
                        <Button variant="outline-success" href="/">Dowiedz się więcej o nas</Button>
                    }
                    {props.isLogged &&
                        <Button variant="outline-success" href="/account">Moje konto</Button>
                    }
                </Nav>

            </Navbar>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where or how does the `"/account"` path/component consume the `isLogged` state?

Comment: The `/account` doesn't consume `isLogged`, it is used in `DefaultNavbar` component where it decides wheather or not show account button

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question/issue initially, but I have found what I believe is the cause and have answered below. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You are rendering react-bootstrap `Button` components with a `href` prop which renders an `<a>` element. This reloads the page and your app, so the `isLogged` state is reset.

## Solution

Import the `Link` component from `react-router-dom` and render it in the `react-bootstrap` `Button` component.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Button
  as={Link}
  to="/account"
  variant="outline-success"
>
  Test
</Button>
```

DefaultNavBar

```
function DefaultNavbar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar bg="warning">
        <Navbar.Brand>
          <Image src={logo} />
        </Navbar.Brand>

        <Nav className="ml-auto">
          {props.isLogged ? (
            <Button variant="outline-success" as={Link} to="/account">
              Moje konto
            </Button>
          ) : (
            <Button variant="outline-success" as={Link} to="/">
              Dowiedz się więcej o nas
            </Button>
          )}
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit change-of-hook-state-in-other-component-is-not-permanent-when-component-is-unmou]